# Achieving the image expand / contract effect

Tags: javascript, css

i want to make the same effect that http://www.userreport.com/ has with their twitter bar in the side, i see that they expand the width of the image when .hover is on, but when i try to

```
width:47px
```

it shrinks the image rather then cutting it, (I am shrinking the div that is holding the image), and do they use JS or do they just manipulate CSS to achieve the effect?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
div.twitter { 
   width: 100px;
   left: 100%;
   margin-left: -50px;
   transition: margin-left 2s;
}

div.twitter:hover { 
   margin-left: -100px;
}
```

Don't forget the browser prefixes on the `transition`